# What does 'let me break the ice' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I was listening to Britney spears album - ***Blackout***. In the track '*Breaking the ice*' She keeps singing '**Let me break the ice**' to her boyfriend - What does it mean in that context ?

Comment: Have you consulted a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-the-ice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dictionary

> breaking the ice

is a phrase used to describe initiating a social interaction, for example when starting a conversation with someone you do not know and have just met.  Figuratively, the situation can be said to be "frozen" (ice) or awkward since no one has initiated the "first move".

In her song, Spears' situation is with her boyfriend, so obviously they already know each other. Spears is describing the situation as "awkward" for her boyfriend since they are about to have sex.  We do not know why it is "awkward", possibly it is the first time, but Spears wants things to happen and is initiating the action.

Answer (score 0):

It means to say something to relieve tension or get conversation going.